# Why can you not specify var/val loops in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why can't you specify a val or var type in for loop's in Kotlin. For example, I would like to be able to do

```
    for (var i in 0...data.size - 1) {
        for (j in 0..bytes.size - 1) {
            bytes[j] = data[i++]//cant do i++ in current kotlin because "i" is val
        }
        //do stuff
    }
```

But instead I have to do this

```
    var i = 0
    while (i < data.size) {
        for (j in 0..bytes.size - 1) {
            bytes[j] = data[i++]
        }
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: This question seems rather opinion-based to me. Probably https://discuss.kotlinlang.org or https://kotlinlang.slack.com are better places for discussing language design questions like this one. As for me, I would find this construct confusing, because `for (item in items) { ... }` has iteration semantics, and your construct with `var` doesn't, instead it requires the `item` to be changed in the body, thus introducing more confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is slightly different from Java's typical `for(int i=0;i<data.size;i++)` example. 
In the Kotlin version 'i' is actually an element of the range in which case i++ doesn't make sense. It just so happens that the range you have is a list of indexes.

The way you are using the Kotlin for loop is much closer to Java's foreach loop `for(i : indexes)`.

Comment: Using i.inc() solved my issue. Thanks for explaination!

Answer (score 3):

I think that because Kotlin is a language that tries to make easy to respect most of the functional programming concepts, it prefers to prohibit that sort of behaviour. Also, a possible problem that your initial code could encount is an OutOfBoundException in the situation where the bytes array has more elements than the data array.